# Android 6.0+，How to get the history access record of the system browser?

Tags: android, browser, browser-history

6.0 the system below can be used READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and ContentpPovider to obtain.On the Android 6.0+ system, how to get a web page history access record for the system browser?

Comment: There is no "system browser" in Android. An Android device may have zero, one, or several pre-installed Web browsers, and users can skip all of them and use something else. None have to expose browsing history to other apps.

Comment: I mean the browser on the mobile phone, there may be more than one. Do you have a way to get the browsing record?

Comment: There is no requirement for any Web browser to expose browsing history to other apps.

Comment: thanks!As far as I know,API<23 is available before, through the content provider query.There is no requirement for any Web browser to expose browsing history to other apps.